# jquery-ui from a bookmarklet

Tags: jquery-ui, bookmarklet

I'm trying to create a bookmarklet which will use the jquery-ui - what steps must I take to do this? My bookmarklet loads a remote script and appends it to the page. This script includes jquery and jquery-ui, but getting the stylesheets and images is turning into a nightmare. Do I have to edit all the CSS to point images to their locations on the remote server?

Effectively what I'm trying to do is have a bookmarklet which will pop up some information in a nice pretty draggable jquery-ui dialog. Is there an easier way?

Thanks,

Mala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the same, but I had no problems to load images. 
To load the jquery ui images, I just used the google cdn server. That worked without any problems. 
To load items from a master webpage, I had to upload a script which returns the complete host url.

Comment: could you point me in the direction of instructions for using the google cdn server please?

Comment: the complete docu can be found under: http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/
you can also load the css files directly by loading "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" for example